# Unable to understand the error in a simple CUDA function

Tags: cuda

Recently I started learning CUDA. Here is my simple code for printing from a kernel.

```
#include"cuPrintf.cu"
#include"cuPrintf.cuh"
#include<cuda.h>
#include<stdio.h>
__global__ void cuprint()
{
     cuPrintf("He he, I am printing from here");
}
main()
{
     cuprint<<<1,1>>>cuprint();
}
```

`cuPrintf.cu` and `cuPrintf.cuh` are downloaded and kept in the directory where I wrote this program. I am getting the following error.

```
cuprint.cu(11): error: expected a "("
cuprint.cu(13): error: expected a declaration
```

Can any one tell me why I am getting those errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling it the wrong way, you should call it like `cuprint<<<1,1>>>();`
And according to this page: https://code.google.com/p/stanford-cs193g-sp2010/wiki/TutorialHelloWorld you need to add some more functions (for init() and stuff)), but I can not confirm that because I have no CUDA PC here)

Comment: This removes my errors. But cuPrintf is not printing any thing on my screen

Comment: Which CUDA version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I meant which computing capability?

Comment: i am using a computing capability of 3.5

Comment: Look above for possible solution

Comment: There is no need of using `cuPrintf` with CUDA `6.0` and a card with compute capability `3.5`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

There is no need to use `cuPrintf` with CUDA `6.0` and a card with compute capability `3.5`.

This simple code will work

```
#include<stdio.h>

__global__ void cuprint()
{
    printf("Printing...\n");
}

main()
{
    cuprint<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: calling a __host__ function("printf") from a __global__ function("cuprint") is not allowed

Comment: @user130004 Are you compiling for the correct compute capability?